# Dict comprehension Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dict with dict comprehension where `self.students[i]` are some names and `j` should be 0,2,4,6,8.

Right now `x` returns

```
{'Patricia': 6, 'Roger': 6, 'Samantha': 6, 'Xander': 6}
```

What I want it to return is

```
{'Patricia': 0, 'Roger': 2, 'Samantha': 4, 'Xander': 6}`
```

Here is the code

```
x = {self.students[i] : j for i in range(0,len(self.students)) for j in range(0,len(self.students)+3, 2)}
```

Comment: What is your **input** and what is your expected **output**?

Answer (score 5):

Use `enumerate`:

```
x = {student : i * 2 for i, student in enumerate(self.students)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `range` when looping over a list, you can just loop over the list itself.  Also, you don't need to use a 2nd loop for `j`, you can just calculate your number based off of the index in the list.

To get the indexes as you loop, you can use `enumerate`.

```
x = {student:i*2 for i,student in enumerate(self.students)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is looping through every student every time.

Hence on the last loop, when `j = 6`, all of the values are changed to `6`.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
students = ['Ivan', 'Masha', 'Sasha']
students_dict = {i: k*2 for k, i in enumerate(students)}
print(students_dict)
```

What you were doing was looping twice. This is used for making 2 dimensional lists. To understand your old code better, see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

`zip` the range with the list to get pairs of values, instead of using nested `for` loops (which are overwriting each value in turn across the entire dict, leaving you with only the last value of `j`):

```
>>> students = ['Patricia', 'Roger', 'Samantha', 'Xander']
>>> {s: j for s, j in zip(students, range(0, len(students) * 2, 2))}
{'Patricia': 0, 'Roger': 2, 'Samantha': 4, 'Xander': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip to build the dictionary from its keys combined with an even number counter (from itertools):

```
x = dict(zip(self.students,itertools.count(0,2)))
```